# Where to call unregisterReceiver in AccessibilityService

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, accessibility

I'm a bit confused. An AccessibilityService can get all new incomming notifications and send information with a Broadcast to a BroadcastReceiver. My AccessibilityService does so

```
public void onServiceConnected() {
    // ...
    Communication c = new Communication();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction("com.cilenco.lockscreen.notification.send");
    registerReceiver(c, filter);
}   

Intent intent=new Intent("com.cilenco.lockscreen.notification.send");

intent.putExtra("string1", string1);
intent.putExtra("string2", string2);

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

After I send the Broadcast the AccessibilityService is still alive. If a new notification is detected onServiceConnected is called again but then the Reciever is connected again in I never called

```
unregisterReceiver(c);
```

Where do I have to call this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `unregisterReceiver()` when you no longer want to receive broadcasts. Convention is that it is called in your `onPause()`. Or sonner if you have no need for it anymore.

Comment: Can I call `registerReceiver(c, filter); sendBroadcast(intent); unregisterReceiver(c);` directly one after another? Then I wouldn't call `registerReceiver(c, filter);` in the onServiceConnected. Is that okay?

Comment: Where exactly would you call the regiester, send, and unregister methods then? Like in your onCreate, or where?

Comment: I do not realy have an Activity or something with onCreate. I have this AccessibilityService, send it to a BroadcastReceiver and there I start a new Service but the first step is that the AccessibilityService has to detect a new Notification.

Comment: It may not be a problem calling all of those within your onServiceConnected method then.

Answer (score 0):

You should call unregisterReceiver() when you no longer need to listen for intents or when your service's onDestroy() is called, whichever comes first.